# Broken PDF document when downloading from web application

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat8

I have a "simple" problem downloading a PDF, Zip or XLSX auto-generated file in Spring MVC.

I have an `Exporter` component that is capable of exporting a dataset into CSV,PDF,XLSX (plain or compressed) formats directly to a generic `OutputStream`.

Running it in JUnit with temporary files as target `OutputStream`s succeeds. However, if I run that component using Spring MVC's auto-wired response `OutputStream` then the response gets corrupted

```
@RequestMapping("/export")
public void export(@RequestBody ..., HttpServletResponse response)
        throws IOException, ExportException
{
    webExportService.export(MyEntity.class, exportRequest, sessionFactory, response.getOutputStream(), response);
}


public <T> void export(Class<T> clazz, RequestBean exportInfo, SessionFactory sessionFactory, OutputStream outputStream,
                       HttpServletResponse httpResponse) {
    httpResponse.setContentType(getMimeType());
    httpResponse.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + getFileName() + "");

    httpResponse.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
    httpResponse.setHeader("Cache-control", "must-revalidate");

    export(clazz, exportInfo, sessionFactory, outputStream); //this will write to the outputStream
}
```

**[Edit] MAJOR REPHRASE REQUIRED**. Sorry now that I re-read the question I found I phrased it bad

When I try to open files of ZIP, PDF and XLSX types, those files cannot be opened by their default editors. Opening them with Notepad++, compared to a temporary folder copy, shows something interesting. The binary characters are different in the two files, like in the example below:

Good
[image: Nonsense]
Bad
[image: Nonsense]

Output stream is type `org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteOutputStream`.

It looks like it is a content encoding problem. How do I find out the correct encoding for those files, if leaving to default is not working?

Side note: I initially posted that the files were "truncated", because opening them (with Notepad++, not mentioned in early question) showed up just a few dozen lines. That looked being correct, I was misleaded by the small size of the file and thought that a double newline was cutting the response entity

Comment: Where does `httpResponse` come from, is that a separate method?

Comment: The `httpResponse` fragment is a fragment of the `export` method. Let me expand...

Comment: @approxiblue sorry I needed to rephrase the question as the early version was misleading about the real problem. It is a character encoding problem, likely

Comment: where in your code does the `OutputStream` get created?

Comment: It is injected by Spring MVC, see http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-arguments

Comment: Are you using flush ?, then that you report is generated?